# Aplying style to a list item dynamically in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have got a list and I want to apply a different style to each item depending on it's Id. Below is my attempt to do that but unfortunately something is wrong. Any help will be very appreciated.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{       
    @if (@item.Id==0)
    {
        var css = "background-color:Aqua";        
    }
    else if (@item.Id==1)
    {
        var css = "background-color:Red";
    }
    else
    {
        var css = "background-color:Green";
    }

    <div style="@css" class="box">
        @item.Info
    </div>
    <div>
        @item.Name
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What's the generated value of the style attribute for the different possible ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is already in a code block(*`foreach code..`*). So no need of `@` . Also define the `css` varibale outside of your `if-else` blocks

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{     
    var css="background-color:Green";  
    @if (@item.Id==0)
    {
        css = "background-color:Aqua";        
    }
    else if (@item.Id==1)
    {
        css = "background-color:Red";
    }
    <div style="@css" class="box"> @item.Info </div>
    <div> @item.Name </div>
}
```

Another solution is creating a css class name string inside your loop using your `item.Id` or `item.Code`(*if that exists*) and using that in your markup. With this approach, you may completely eliminate the if condition checking in your razor code, thus making this a much cleaner solution than the previous one.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="box myClass-@item.Id">
        @item.Name
    </div>
   <div> @item.Name </div>
}
```

And in your css class add the css classes as needed

```
.myClass-0
{
  background-color:aqua;
}
.myClass-1
{
  background-color:red;
}
.myClass-2
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

Id's might change, so i recommend using some other properties like Code/Name etc.

Comment: Giving the `css` a default value would be wiser.

Comment: There's really no need to define those css classes, and if there's some common characteristics to be shared, one css class would suffice and the guy could still use the style. You know when we can do inline style why not using it, it really isn't a bad practice but many think they should stick with classes. It's a matter of personal taste though, just wanted to share my opinion :D

Comment: I personally prefer to keep minimum C# code in my razor views : ) Yea, that is just me :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try setting a default style and bring `var css` out of the if block, then set the value according to your needs.
But you can also try a helper for that:

```
@helper styler(int id, String value){
    var bg = "background-color:white" // as default
    if(id == 1){
        bg = "Another color";
    }
    else if (id == 2) {
      // continue setting values
    }
    <span style="@bg">@value</span>
 }
```

However, this is not really necessary as you can set the style inside of the for loop, but this approach reduce some code duplication.